# How to determine if a PHPUnit test is runnig?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I need to determine if I'm running a PHPUnit test in my php code or if I'm requesting a page normally via browser. I tried setting env variables and constants in phpunit.xml, but both turn out to be unset when I make requests with Guzzle to my endpoints.

I'm running the in-built php server if it makes a difference.

Comment: (Normally) the code under test should not contain different paths whether it is in a test or not. This is just because you otherwise wouldn't test the (production) code. Anyway, what prevents you from adding a request header in the test situation you can easily differ a test-request from a non-test request?

Comment: Just wanted to use in-memory sqlite for my tests. Didn't think about adding a header, that might be an option, thank you!